# Did any major polluters take up any significant steps towards fulfilling the Paris Agreement?

Tags: international, climate-change, paris-agreement

Today is the day when the US will officially leave the Paris Agreement that was signed by Obama back in 2016. This is claimed to be a major setback for the Green movement in the US. But did any major polluters take up any significant steps in the past four years towards curbing their emissions?

To narrow the question, by "major polluters" I'm referring to individual countries that make up 50% of [the worlds pollution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_carbon_dioxide_emissions) when combined with the US: China, India, Russia, Japan and Germany. And a "significant step" would be a binding policy that has already taken effect, rather than a mere intent to do something in the distant future such as [California's ban on internal combustion engines](https://www.theverge.com/2020/9/23/21452825/california-ban-combustion-gas-vehicles-cars-2035) that will take place 15 years from now.

Comment: If 15 years is distant future, then what are you looking for?  Climate change is an issue on scales up to 100-300 years, and you can hardly expect a country to ban internal combustion engines overnight.

Comment: @gerrit I'm looking for something specific that the US could've been expected to do by now if only it didn't leave the agreement. In other words, I'm trying to understand what exactly would've been the difference between our world and a parallel universe where Clinton won and didn't leave the agreement.

Comment: Depending on your definition of "significant" that may be very broad that could include many policies in the mentioned countries.  I could list some policies that Germany has implemented but the US hasn't.  It's not enough according to science (regardless of politics), so arguably not significant enough, but maybe it's still significant?

Comment: Note that if California where its own country it would be a maor polluter, slightly smaller than Germany but not much. Banning interenal combustion engines (if it applies to all vehicles on the road and not just new ones) will also have a significant effect on the total CO2 emission of California.

Comment: "Major polluters" should not be defined in terms of high total carbon emissions, but high per capita emissions. Calling India and China major polluters is like claiming that Africa has a bigger obesity problem than the US because of its population's combined bodymass is larger than the US'.

Comment: Even if an ICE ban only takes effect 15 years ago, the horizon of such a ban will likely impact sales of ICE vs. electric engines immediately.  If it applies to all cars on the road including those from other states, that effect will extend beyond the borders of California (caveat: I don't know the specifics of this ban at all).

Comment: @quarague California's decision could be overruled by the Federal government thanks to the Commerce Clause, so it's not final even if it actually becomes a law in 15 years.

Comment: @ijm in terms of climate change **only** absolute emissions matter. The polar caps will not be saved by Norway or Sweden alone going green.

Comment: @gerrit that specific ban is toothless without the Federal governments approval due to the Commerce Clause. As of today it's just an empty declaration of intent. We'll find out if they will (or be allowed to) walk the walk in 2035.

Comment: @JonathanReez Not only absolute emissions matter, take-up of CO₂ also matters, therefore deforestation is a major issue (such as in the Amazon).  Your point about only Norway or Sweden going green [is accurate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tragedy_of_the_commons), which is why many outside the USA care what the USA does (also due to the indirect effect a USA decision may have on decisions in other countries). It also matters what greenhouse gases are emitted (CO₂, CH₄, others) and where (lower troposphere, UTLS, other). But that's an [EarthScience.SE] question, not a Politics one.

Comment: @JonathanReez NB: Several European cities have [low-emission zones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-emission_zone), and usually courts accept the argument of air quality.  CO₂ is not an air quality issue, but all-electric vehicles can solve both problems (urban air quality in any case, CO₂ depending on how the electricity is generated).  So I can imagine that depending on how such a ban is formulated, it might well stand in court.

Comment: @gerrit minor point, Amazon trees are not particularly effective at reducing the amount of carbon dioxide in the atmosphere: https://www.nationalgeographic.com/environment/2019/08/why-amazon-doesnt-produce-20-percent-worlds-oxygen/

Comment: @gerrit California cannot introduce it's own environmental standards without the Federal governments approval: https://www.nytimes.com/2019/09/17/climate/trump-california-emissions-waiver.html. An individual city will likewise be powerless to override Washington.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/115914/discussion-between-gerrit-and-jonathanreez).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A [carbon tax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbon_tax) will come into force in Germany from January 2021.  It will initially be set at €25/tonne and increased to €55/tonne in 2025 (1 tonne = 1000 kg).  Whether this is significant is a subjective question.  Germany also [made carbon targets legally binding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Climate_change_in_Germany#Climate_change_policy) in 2019, so that when it can be shown policies are insufficient to meet targets, courts can force the government to enact better policies.

India reportedly has a carbon tax of 400 Rs/tonne, or around €4.57.

By comparison, Sweden has had a carbon tax since 1991, which has been around €100 since 2007 and has reportedly contributed significantly to the elimination of fossil fuel domestic heating.  The [New York Times reports that the IPCC  estimates](https://www.nytimes.com/2018/10/07/climate/ipcc-climate-report-2040.html) that a carbon tax *would have to range from $135 to $5,500 per ton of carbon dioxide pollution in 2030, and from $690 to $27,000 per ton by 2100*.  Compared to those numbers, green politicians have argued that the proposed German carbon tax is too low and will not help enough.

Have major polluters done *something*?  Yes, at least Germany has.  Its impact may be too small to meet the carbon targets by itself, but it can still be politically significant that a carbon tax is introduced at all.

Comment: Why the downvotes?